# Evaluate parenthesis expression for correct nesting and matching parens

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please review this solution for matching parens for correctness and nesting.

```
def matchParens(pstring):
    plist = [l for l in pstring]
    newlist = []
    if plist[0] == ')' or plist.count('(') != plist.count(')') or plist[-1::] == '(':
        return False
    while len(plist) > 0:
        head, *tail = plist
        if head == '(':
            newlist.append(plist.pop(plist.index(head)))
            right = tail.index(')')
            if isinstance(right, int):
                newlist.append(plist.pop(right))
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use `snake_case` (`matchParens`)
- You are checking a property, so I would name your function `has_correct_parens` to make it clearer that this function return `True` or `False`
- `[i for i in iterable]` is a longer way of saying `list(iterable)` so `plist = [l for l in pstring]` should become `plist = list(pstring)`
- The preventive check should be at the start for clarity and efficiency
- What if you will want to use square / curly / triangular parens in the future? I would use constants:

```
OPEN_PAREN = '('
CLOSE_PAREN = ')'
```

Answer (score 2):

To only check whether the parenthesis are balanced you don't need to manipulate the string that you check (you are creating sublists of that string, in worst case about half as many as there are characters).

My other complaint about your function is that it expects strings made up of parenthesis only: it's hard to think about an actual use case for that. Typically, you'd like to match something of that format where there are other characters allowed between parenthesis.

I would also question the choice of the algorithm which requires you to write an early exit condition. It is typically perceived as "more elegant" to have the code of the algorithm to cover all cases.

Below is some code, which I think is a typical code anyone would write if asked to do the task:

```
def balanced_parenthesis(input, open = '(', close = ')'):
    opened = 0
    for char in input:
        if char == open:
            opened += 1
        elif char == close and opened > 0:
            opened -= 1
        elif char == close:
            return False
    return opened == 0
```

Why would I chose this version? Well, beside other things I already said, it's clear from the implementation that the algorithm does strictly linear job (whereas when you call `index()` in the body of the loop which might look at all characters of a string, that isn't immediately obvious).

Comment: NIcely coded, very similar to what I came up with. Just remember to use `for char in input` instead of `range(len(input))`

Comment: @Caridorc yes, right, I started with a different approach and totally forgot about it.